# File Upload Rspec Integration Negative Test Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paperclip, integration-testing

I have a couple custom validators I'm using to validate a paperclip attachment is an image and not over 5MB. Everything works as expected

I'm a bit curious about one thing though. My integration test checks weather `user.avatar` is nil after a failed upload, and it's returning something kind of random.

The test:

```
 it 'Does not allow a non-image file to be uploaded as an avatar' do
   visit edit_user_path(@user)
   attach_file('user_avatar', File.dirname(__FILE__)+'/users_spec.rb')
   click_button 'Update'
   page.should have_content "Avatar must be an image"
   @user.reload
   @user.avatar.should be_nil
 end
```

The result:

```
1) Users Avatars Does not allow a non-image file to be uploaded as an avatar
 Failure/Error: @user.avatar.should be_nil
   expected: nil
        got: /avatars/original/missing.png
 # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:147:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm guessing that this is some kind of default placeholder paperclip is sticking in there, however when I go to the user `show` page, `@user.avatar` is `nil` as expected. What gives?

I've also tried, to the same result

```
@user.should_not have_attached_file(:avatar)
```

Which given that it's paperclips own matcher, seems like it should work, but it fails as well

After a couple of puts statements, it appears `@user.avatar` yields `/avatars/original/missing.png` before anything has been done to it, so I guess I can at least be sure that it hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! The file? method returns true if a file is attached to the given field, so the following code gave me the test I wanted:

```
@user.avatar.file?.should be_false
```